# error occured when i trying to flash micropython in esp 32-s model

Tags: esp32

```
python -m esptool --chip esp32 --port COM5 --baud 460800 write_flash -z 0x1000 esp32-20220618-v1.19.1.elf
esptool.py v4.6.2
Serial port COM5
Connecting.....
Chip is ESP32-D0WD (revision v1.0)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: a8:48:fa:0a:bb:b4
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...

A fatal error occurred: File esp32-20220618-v1.19.1.elf (length 25272412) at offset 4096 will not fit in 4194304 bytes of flash. Use --flash_size argument, or change flashing address.
```

how to solv this problem

Comment: Hi Dharmik, you're flashing a 25 MB image but the tool assumes a Flash size of 4 MB. Since you haven't provided any other information, the conclusions and corrective action are up to you. Meanwhile please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)